# Parse PHP page and insert HTML into variable

Tags: php, html, file

Is it possible to have a template file in PHP like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>sdfds</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="some-content">
        <?php some_content(); ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and load it into a variable, without echoing it, but still parsing the results of `some_content()`. Let say `some_content()` echoed `<p>oh yes!</p>` then this need to be part of the content in the variable. The reason why this is important, is that i need to return the content instead of echoing it.

I have looked at `file_get_contents()` but that is not going to parse the php, so the div is left empty. I need something like `parse_file_and_get_content()`.

Comment: did you write `some_content()` is this user defined?

Comment: Have you considered using an output buffer or a true template where you don't need to execute PHP inside of it but rather replace some string identifier?

Comment: Look into output buffering

Comment: @ghost yeah, some_content() is a custom function. Just an example.

Comment: @MaltheMilthers if you just want your function to return a string, have you tried just `return '<p>oh yes!</p>';`

Comment: @ghost thats not my problem. I want to read the entire file "post php parsing" and get the resulting html into a variable. Ouput buffering might be the answer

Comment: @PeeHaa: Are there any downsides to output buffering? is it consider good practice? I have never used it before.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible, with the output buffering system.

```
ob_start();
include("your_external_php_file.php");
$parsed_html = ob_get_clean();
```

`include()` will execute any `<?php ... ?>` code blocks in the file, and the OB system will capture any output performed by that file while the buffer is active. Then you fetch the buffer's contents and now `$parsed_html` has all of that html, along with anything output by your php function call in there.

Comment: This seems to work exactly like I want. Thanks!. Follow up: are there any downsides or limitation when using the buffering system?

Comment: Not really downsides. The problem is that you're not fixing the root 'problem' (by using some kind of templating engine), but instead try to fix the outcome/consequences.

Comment: @Rik_S: php **IS** a templating engine. There is NOTHING wrong with what OP's doing and is essentially what all the other php-based templating engines are doing, except they slap own their own bloated/unreadable syntax and parsing overhead.

Comment: I disagree with saying PHP **IS** a templating engine. I however agree with you that in essence, nothing's wrong with using ob_* functions for templating, and can even speed up your site by compressing the buffer output. Like I said, no real downsides to doing it the way described.

Comment: @Rik_S: I think i get what you mean by not fixing the root problem - but in my use case it needs to work in the context of wordpress where PHP is definitely used as a templating engine, and so i need it to use functions instead of {{some content}} style templating with str_replace() - if that is what Marc B is referring to with "other php-based templating engines".